# Animation Problem

Tags: iphone, animation, xamarin.ios

i have a view class and a custom button class. view has 4 instances of these custom buttons.

custom button class fires an event. view class uses this event and start animation to resize all buttons. it maximize the event generator button and minimize others. animation for the event generator button does not work. for other buttons, animation works. animation for the event generator button behaves like the animation time is zero. it immediately maximize the button.

it seems this code just animates position, not the size. how can i animate the size parameter?

is it bug or it is normal? or is it a ui thread problem?

this code is from view class;

```
void HandleButtonClick (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BestButton[] buttons = { best1, best2, best3, best4 };

    UIView.BeginAnimations ("AnimateLabel");
    UIView.SetAnimationDuration (2);
    UIView.SetAnimationDidStopSelector (new Selector ("didFinishAnimation:"));
    UIView.SetAnimationDelegate (this);

    var max = new RectangleF (0, 0, 320, 460);
    var min = new RectangleF (0, 0, 0, 0);

    foreach (var item in buttons) {
        if (sender == item)
            item.Frame = max;
        else
            item.Frame = min;
        }

    UIView.CommitAnimations ();
}
```

Comment: If its UI related, it can't hurt to wrap your `foreach` loop in `InvokeOnMainThread (delegate { // code });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution. i deleted this line and everything works now.

```
UIView.SetAnimationDelegate (this);
```